# My laptop won't turn back on after suspending in 20.04.1. Any ideas?

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I have an ASUS x550za dualbooting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.1. If I try to suspend my laptop, it turns off properly and seems totally fine. But when I try to boot it again, it gets stuck on a black screen (with the backlight on), forcing me to press and hold the power button to switch it off.

The same thing happens in Windows 10 when trying to sleep, though hibernating works perfectly.

Other than a new WiFi card, and extra 8 gig stick of RAM, and an SSD, my computer has stock components.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: Now that I think about it, this might've been a bad BIOS update. I'll try downgrading the version to see what happens.